# Only display one array item at a time (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to essentially create a ticker which shows a single string item taken from an array at a time. Basically I just want it to show a single item and then transition into the next, my Javascript skills are massively rudimentary (Jquery might be better for this.)

Here is my code:

```
var title= ['Orange', 'Apple', 'Mango', 'Airplane', 'Kiwi'];
for (var i=0; i<title.length; i++){
document.write(title[i]);
}
```

What do I have to add?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: *"my Javascript skills are massively rudimentary"*  vs. *"Jquery might be better for this"*. **No!** _First_ master the language, _then_ use a framework to get rid of all nasty things. Also, currently you're only writing all things at once. You should learn about DOM manipulation.

Comment: Don't use document.write, read up on using innerHTML.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start by learning about `document.getElementById` and `setInterval`.

http://jsfiddle.net/wtNhf/

HTML:

```
<span id="fruit"></span>
```

Javascript:

```
var title = ['Orange', 'Apple', 'Mango', 'Airplane', 'Kiwi'];

var i = 0;  // the index of the current item to show

setInterval(function() {            // setInterval makes it run repeatedly
    document
        .getElementById('fruit')
        .innerHTML = title[i++];    // get the item and increment i to move to the next
    if (i == title.length) i = 0;   // reset to first element if you've reached the end
}, 1000);                           // 1000 milliseconds == 1 second
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/3fj9E/1/

js

```
 var span = $('span');
 var div = 0;
 var fading_in = function () {
 $(span[div++] || []).fadeIn(500, arguments.callee);
 }
setTimeout(fading_in, 400);
```

html

```
 <div id='example'>
 <span>orange </span>
 <span>apple </span>
 <span>kiwi </span>
<span>banana </span>
<span> melon</span>
</div>
```

css

```
 span {display:none}
```

Comment: it's a different way than doing a set interval for html elements that are essentially in a dom array

Answer (score 0):

I tried to keep it at its simplest

HTML

```
<div id="my_id"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var counter = 0;
var words = ['jaja', 'jojo', 'lol', 'troll', 'pk!'];
var my_div = document.getElementById('my_id');

function next_word()
{
    my_div.innerHTML = words[counter % words.length];
    counter += 1;
}

setInterval(next_word, 100);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zTLqe/