# Display one item at a time in scope array

Tags: angularjs

How do I show one item at a time in the scope array?

I've tried a couple variations of this but either way all items in the scope appear at once.  Ideally I'd like to have one item in the scope appear for a given time then move on to the next one.

```
function intervalCtrl($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.start = function () {           
        var items = [
            { name: "example 1", title: "example title 1"},
            { name: "example 2", title: "example title 2"},
            { name: "example 3", title: "example title 3"}
        ];

        $interval(function () {
            for(var i = 0; i <= items.length; i++){
                  //console.log(items[i]);
                  $scope.items = items[i];
            }                
        }, 3000);                                                        
    }
}
```

I used [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691972/only-display-one-array-item-at-a-time-javascript) article to model after a few times.  I can even get it working using setInterval but since using angular should just use the $interval.

Thanks

Comment: do you wanted to have carousel effect?

Comment: doesnt really matter I just need to get the items displaying one at time first then can add the animation in later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. Does this do what you were looking for?

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('MyController', function($scope, $interval) {

  var items = [{
    name: "example 1",
    title: "example title 1"
  }, {
    name: "example 2",
    title: "example title 2"
  }, {
    name: "example 3",
    title: "example title 3"
  }];


  $scope.start = function() {
    $scope.currentItem = items[0];
    $scope.currentIndex = 1;
    $interval(function() {
      $scope.currentItem = items[$scope.currentIndex];
      $scope.currentIndex++;
      if ($scope.currentIndex >= items.length) {
        $scope.currentIndex = 0;
      }
    }, 1000);

  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <button ng-click="start()">Start</button>
    <br/>Name: {{currentItem.name}}
    <br/>Title: {{currentItem.title}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the current index outside of `$interval` callback like so:

```
var current = -1;
var handle = null;
$scope.start = function () {           
    var items = [
        { name: "example 1", title: "example title 1"},
        { name: "example 2", title: "example title 2"},
        { name: "example 3", title: "example title 3"}
    ];

    handle = $interval(function () {
        current = (current + 1) % items.length;
        $scope.item = items[current];
    }, 3000);                                                        
}

$scope.stop = function(){
   $interval.cancel(handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function intervalCtrl($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.start = function() {           
        var items = [
            { name: "example 1", title: "example title 1"},
            { name: "example 2", title: "example title 2"},
            { name: "example 3", title: "example title 3"}
        ];
        var i = 0;
        $scope.items = items[i];  
        $interval( function () {
            i++;  
            $scope.items = items[i];
        }, 3000,items.length);                                                        
    }
}
```

The `$interval` function will be called `items.length` times.

This would work.