# How can I display elements one at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to display one element at a time. They come from a JSON file. I am using JQuery and setInterval. But the images should change based on the file's "Milliseconds'

What am I doing wrong? 
my implementation is based on [Only display one array item at a time (Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691972/only-display-one-array-item-at-a-time-javascript)

JSON FILE

```
{
  "Name": "2",
  "PlaylistItems": [
    {
       "FileName": "ad1.png",
       "Duration": "00:00:23",
       "Milliseconds": 1300.0
    },
    {
       "FileName": "ad2.jpg",
       "Duration": "00:00:00",
       "Milliseconds": 25000.0
    },
    {
       "FileName": "ad3.png",
       "Duration": "00:00:00",
       "Milliseconds": 5400.0
    }

  ]
}
```

Javascript

```
function DisplayMessages() {

    $.getJSON(screenSettingsUrl, (data) => {
      if (data != null) {

      var i = 0;


    setInterval(() => {

      divName.css("background-image", "url(./media/" + data.PlaylistItems[i].FileName + ")");
      divName.css("background-repeat", "no-repeat");
      i++;

      if(i == data.PlaylistItems.length) i = 0;

    }, data.PlaylistItems[i].Milliseconds);
  }
   });
}
 DisplayMessages();
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `data.PlaylistItems[i].Milliseconds` is never repeated.  You are creating a single interval, and nothing you do to change the `i` variable is going to change the delay you created it with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have different **Milliseconds** values setInterval is not the best choice. In this case i would suggest setTimeout and a recursive approach.

```js
var data = {
    "Name": "2",
    "PlaylistItems": [
        {
            "FileName": "ad1.png",
            "Duration": "00:00:23",
            "Milliseconds": 1300.0
        },
        {
            "FileName": "ad2.jpg",
            "Duration": "00:00:00",
            "Milliseconds": 2500.0
        },
        {
            "FileName": "ad3.png",
            "Duration": "00:00:00",
            "Milliseconds": 5400.0
        }

    ]
};

function DisplayMessages(i) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(data.PlaylistItems[i].FileName);
        i++;
        if (i < data.PlaylistItems.length) DisplayMessages(i);
    }, data.PlaylistItems[i].Milliseconds);
}

DisplayMessages(0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using timeouts to perform a recursive loop on your array.

```js
function DisplayMessages() {
  $.getJSON(screenSettingsUrl, (data) => {
    var i = 0;
    
    if (data != null) {
      function displayNextItem () {
        //show the current image
        divName.css("background-image", "url(./media/" + data.PlaylistItems[i].FileName + ")");
        divName.css("background-repeat", "no-repeat");
        //advance i to the next image, or back to 0 if it reaches the end
        //of the array
        i = ++i % data.PlaylistItems.length;
        
        //start the loop for the next element, with it's timeout
        setTimeout(displayNextImage, data.PlaylistItems[i].Milliseconds);
      }
      
      //start the loop on the first element, with it's timeout
      setTimeout(displayNextImage, data.PlaylistItems[i].Milliseconds);
    }
  });
}

DisplayMessages();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and solution.